# takeOrdered descending Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark

i would like to sort K/V pairs by values and then take the biggest five values. I managed to do this with reverting K/V with first map, sort in descending order with FALSE, and then reverse key.value to the original (second map) and then take the first 5 that are the bigget, the code is this:

```
RDD.map(lambda x:(x[1],x[0])).sortByKey(False).map(lambda x:(x[1],x[0])).take(5)
```

i know there is a takeOrdered action on pySpark, but i only managed to sort on values (and not on key), i don't know how to get a descending sorting:

```
RDD.takeOrdered(5,key = lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: RDD.takeOrdered(5, lambda (word,count): -count)

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.takeOrdered

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Sort by keys (ascending):

```
RDD.takeOrdered(5, key = lambda x: x[0])
```

Sort by keys (descending):

```
RDD.takeOrdered(5, key = lambda x: -x[0])
```

Sort by values (ascending):

```
RDD.takeOrdered(5, key = lambda x: x[1])
```

Sort by values (descending):

```
RDD.takeOrdered(5, key = lambda x: -x[1])
```

Comment: i was so close , i've tried 

    RDD.takeOrdered(-5, key = lambda x: x[1])

in order to get the last one you posted.
Thanks

Comment: Very useful! In order to get the first: RDD.takeOrdered(1, key = lambda x: -x[1])