# Sorting a rdd of strings in descending order using takeOrdered

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am new to spark and came across a problem . My RDD is as follows

```
names_rdd = sc.parallelize(["abc","def","ghi", "jkl","mno"]);
```

I am confused about how to use `takeOrdered` command to get top 3 words in descending order . I am expecting the output `["mno", "jkl", "ghi"]` . The strings are ordered lexicographically in descending order

Could someone help me with the problem.

Comment: do your word count as usal and then `yourrdd.takeOrdered(3)(Ordering[Int].reverse.on(x=>x._2))`

Comment: @Ram question is in python

Comment: Did you see this? What attempts did you make? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787635/takeordered-descending-pyspark

Comment: In that example, the input is a integer and descending is done using the lambda function  "lambda x : -x" . I cant do the same for string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A work around,

```
 names_rdd.takeOrdered(3,key=lambda x:-ord(x[0]))

 ['mno', 'jkl', 'ghi']
```